# Nikon 50mm f/1.8 even on manual gives fEE error with D3300?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, error, nikon-d3300

The camera functions fine from f/1.8 all the way to f/22 when I lock the aperture ring at f/22. Whenever I try to use the aperture ring, however, it gives an fEE error and that is even on manual mode and aperture priority. I have checked the lens and can make sure that the aperture ring in fact does correctly change the aperture when it is disconnected from the camera.

Do I have a faulty lens or do I need to change a setting to allow control of the aperture from the lens instead of the camera? As far as I have read, it seems like the D3300 should allow manual control of the aperture from an aperture ring. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Also related: [fEE error using Nikon 85mm1.8 with nikon D80 camera](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/54433)

Comment: Also related: [Fee error on d7000 with 50 mm lens](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/41114)

Answer (score 1):

The D3300 doesn't have an AI tab/feeler on the lens mount to read in the aperture manually set on any lens with a corresponding index edge, so changing the aperture on your lens from f/22 will cause issues, as the 50mm f/1.8 that you own has a chip that is only activated when the aperture ring is set to f/22 (See [AI-P/D-Type Lenses @ Nikon](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/which-nikkor-lens-type-is-right-for-your-dslr.html), [Nikon Lens Acronyms at byThom (AI-P and AF-D)](http://www.bythom.com/lensacronyms.htm)). This chip communicates with the D3300 to allow aperture control and other metering/shooting operations. Note that the f/22 or very smallest aperture is often marked in orange on such Nikon lenses (and similarly on 3rd party lenses) as a hint to this operation.

To change the aperture do either of these things after setting the aperture on the lens to f/22:

**In Aperture (A) mode**: Rotate the rear command dial (you will see visual confirmation on the back of the camera).

**In Manual (M) mode**: Hold down the [+/-] button and rotate the rear command dial (both are on the right-hand/grip side of the camera).

Ref: [See page 70-71 of the Nikon D3300 manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/payY500AHbkQ02bXMhb14TZo4978/D3300_NT(En)02.pdf).